# How to know the browser build-in object in ready in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wechat

The background:
The wechat JS API is on the foundation of wechat build-in browser object WeixinJSBridge. The WeixinJSBridge is not ready immediately when open the WebView,client side need initialize this object， when this object is ready，client side will fire "WeixinJSBridgeReady", so before invoke WeixinJSBridge API， we need check WeixinJSBridge is ready or not:

```
if (typeof WeixinJSBridge == "object" && typeof WeixinJSBridge.invoke == "function") {
    WeixinJSBridge.invoke'API()....
} else {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("WeixinJSBridgeReady", callback, false);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("WeixinJSBridgeReady", callback);
        document.attachEvent("onWeixinJSBridgeReady", callback);
    }
}
```

here is the question: how can I do this check in context of angular, i want put this stuff in one controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Use .run: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.run(/*standard function and scope*/);
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to to do, that would be one solution. Or have angular make a call out, or build a stand alone module containing all of your specific code, and have your app import that module.